# ASP.NET Webforms Accessing Files not in application directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How can I programmatically access files via a url that are located in a directory not in the application directory?  For example, if I have a url like mysite.com that paths to c:\mysite, I want to have a url like:  mysite.com/reports that paths to c:\reports.

Am I able to write code that enables to sniff the incoming url request and map it to the appropriate directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Impersonation using an account which already has access to that folder or give the IIS worker process access to the folder you want.

Comment: You left out "mount the directory in IIS as a Virtual Directory"

Comment: I created a virtual directory in the asp.net app; however, I continue to receive a 404 error.